# Adding Data From XML File Into JS Array Of Objects

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to take data from an XML file and push it into a JS array of Objects.  Here is my JS code:

```
var data = [];

function parseData(xml){
console.log(xml);
var tempObj = {};
$(xml).find('question').each(function(){
    data.push(tempObj);
});

$(xml).find('question').find('clue').each(function(i){
    data[i]['clue'] = $(this).text();
    console.log(data[i]);
});
console.log(data);
}
```

and here is my XML Data (edited for brevity)

```
<exercise>
<question>
    <clue>First letter of greek alphabet</clue>
    ...
</question>
<question>
    <clue>Second letter of greek alphabet</clue>
    ...
</question>
<question>
    <clue>Third letter of greek alphabet</clue>
    ...
</question>
```

When I inspect this in Chrome, it initially looks like it's behaving correctly, but when I view the Objects in more detail, it's actually taking the last `<clue>` and repeating it three times.

[Collapsed Array View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CafTL.png)

[Expanded Array View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOsdL.png) (Can't post images directly because of a reputation less than 10)

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong with this?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some suggestion. I hope you'll take a look at it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using the same object (`tempObj` holds the reference to the same object). You have to redefine `tempObj` for every `"question"`. Here is an example of what's going wrong in your code:

```js
var obj = {}; // declare an object ({}) and store the reference to it inside obj

obj.something = "something";

var otherObj = obj; // here you think that obj is duplicated and that obj and otherObj are two different objects but you're wrong
                    // obj and otherObj holds a reference to the same object.

otherObj.something = "something else";

// proof: obj.something is changed even if we didn't change it because the object it's pointing to has changed
console.log(obj);
```

That exactly what was happening with your code, all the items of the array points to the same object, so when one of them is changed, all of them get changed.

What you need is to redefine `tempObj` (create a new object) for each `"question"` like this:

```
function parseData(xml){
    $(xml).find('question').each(function(){
        var tempObj = {}; // create a brand new object for each iteration
        // fill the tempObj here
        data.push(tempObj);
    });
    // ...
}
```

---

**Advice:** Just want to make a suggestion about your code. Insead of calling `each` twice, you could do this:

```
function parseData(xml){
    $(xml).find('question').each(function(){
        var tempObj = {}; // create a brand new object for each iteration
        data.push(tempObj);

       // you could read the properies of the question here (why use another each to loop through the questions if you are already looping through the questions)
       tempObj['clue'] = $(this).find('clue').text(); // even if data.push is been called before this tempObj will still changes data[i] (because of the same reference thing, got it???)
    });
}
```